# Can an Azure pipeline have multiple pipeline resources referencing the same source?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm using the pipeline resource to trigger a second pipeline from a first pipeline. The two pipelines are in different repositories. They may even be in different projects.

This is the pipeline resource definition in the second pipeline.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: xyz_build
    source: company.xyz_source
    trigger:
      enabled: true
      branches:
        include:
        - develop
        - release/*
```

I want the second pipeline to take different actions, based on whether it was triggered by a build on the `develop` branch or a `release` branch. If an Azure pipeline can handle multiple pipeline resources which reference the same source, then I can rewrite my pipeline resources like this, and then choose different execution paths based on the value of `$(Resources.TriggeringAlias)`.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: xyz_develop_build
    source: company.xyz_source
    trigger:
      enabled: true
      branches:
        include:
        - develop
  - pipeline: xyz_release_build
    source: company.xyz_source
    trigger:
      enabled: true
      branches:
        include:
        - release/*
```

Does this work in Azure Pipelines? Does Azure Pipelines support this?

**EDITED TO ADD:** It runs when I trigger it manually. I guess we'll find out what happens when somebody runs a build on `xyz.source`.

Comment: Also, I wish to complain that it's dumb to call the pipeline name or alias `resources.pipelines.pipeline` and then call the predefined variable `$(Resources.TriggeringAlias)`. Why didn't they call the pipeline alias `resources.pipelines.alias` and the predefined variable `$(Resources.PipelineAlias)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

You can still capture the branch of the source resource from the different repo or even different project. But you can't set conditions at compile time to erase unnecessary tasks at the beginning of compilation(in the same repo, you can).

You can determine conditions at runtime to achieve the purpose of 'skip' tasks.

I provide an example here which have pipelines from two different projects, one for ProjectA and the other for ProjectB:

***ProjectA***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

***ProjectB***

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: ProjectA
    project: ProjectA
    source: ProjectA
    trigger:
      enabled: true
      branches:
        include:
        - develop
        - release

trigger:
- none
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: 
  displayName: Handle ProjectA develop branch
  condition: eq(variables['resources.pipeline.ProjectA.sourceBranch'],'refs/heads/develop')
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Write your PowerShell commands here.
        
        Write-Host "Hello World"
        Write-Host $(resources.pipeline.ProjectA.sourceBranch)
- job: 
  displayName: Handle ProjectA release branch
  condition: eq(variables['resources.pipeline.ProjectA.sourceBranch'],'refs/heads/release')
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Write your PowerShell commands here.
        
        Write-Host "Hello World"
        Write-Host $(resources.pipeline.ProjectA.sourceBranch)
```

**Original Answer:**

For example, pipeline A trigger PipelineB

**PipelineA**

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

**PipelineB**

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PipelineA
    project: xxx
    source: PipelineA
    trigger:
      enabled: true
      branches:
        include:
        - develop
        - release

trigger:
- none
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/develop') }}:
  - script: echo "this is develop branch"
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/release') }}:
  - script: echo "this is release branch"
```

Please make sure both branches have the above YML file(Pipeline will looking for the same name YML file in every branches).

Comment: This only works if both pipelines are in the same repository.

In PipelineB, `Build.SourceBranch` refers to the branch of PipelineB, not the branch of PipelineA.

I need a solution that will work if the pipelines are in different repositories, and even in different Azure Devops projects. I will edit my question to reflect this important point.

Comment: @RayDepew Thanks for clarify, I will update the answer later.:)

Comment: Your revised solution works beautifully.

I have a follow-up question: what other variables can I read from Pipeline A using this technique? Is there a table that translates Predefined Variable names as found in the Azure Pipelines documentation, into `resources.pipeline.foo.bar` format?

Is it possible to pass pipeline parameters, pipeline variables, and queue-time variables using this same technique?

Comment: @RayDepew Simply put, everything that can be printed at runtime can be processed by the technique of 'condition'.

Comment: @RayDepew But you need to notice the usage in this place, refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: @RayDepew If my answer answered your question, could you please accept it as the answer?:)